# How to insert text into textarea through c# with Forms.WebBrowser

Tags: c#, browser

Suppose I had the following HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
   <textarea id="foo"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

How to insert text into the textarea through C# `Htmldocument`?

The `setattribute ()` method is not working as there is no `value` field for `textarea`.

So how to insert `text` into `textarea` through C#?

Any advice is much appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, add a reference to your project for `Microsoft.mshtml`, or if it is not on the list, the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\Microsoft.mshtml.dll`.  Then the C# code would look something like:

```
string myId = "foo";
string myNewValue = "This goes in the Text Area!";

IHTMLDocument2 htmlDoc = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHtmlDocument2;
if (htmlDoc != null)
{
  var textAreaType = typeof(IHTMLTextAreaElemnt);
  IHTMLTextAreaElement htmlTextArea = 
    htmlDoc.All
           .FirstOrDefault(x => textAreaType.IsAssignableFrom(x)
                                && ((IHTMLElement)x).id == myId) 
           as IHTMLTextAreaElement;
  if (htmlTextArea != null)
  {
    htmlTextArea.value = myNewValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Erik, but can you specify the code for C# and that to I added Microsoft.mshtml.tlb refrence from '.\windows\system32' not the Microsoft.mshtml.dll in '..\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Common folder'.

Comment: Thank you for your help Erik but still after adding the refrence of IHTMLDocument2 also its showing an error "The type or namespace name 'IHTMLTextAreaElement' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)",do I need to install any SDK's? or is there any way other than mshtml like with HTMLDocument?

Comment: There is no other way I know of. I did forget to mention you need to add `using mshtml;`